# Compile template class failed by g++ or clang++

Tags: c++, templates, g++, clang++

I wrote the source code as shown below.
----- sample.h ------

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
class Sample {
private:
static int foo;
public:
 Sample (T number) {
foo = number;}
 void display () {
std :: cout << foo << std :: endl;}
};
```

---

---- test.cpp --------------

```
#include "sample.h"
template <> int Sample <float> :: foo;


int main () {
 Sample <float> test (100.9);
 test.display ();
 return 0;
}
```

---

I have successfully compiled with Visual Studio 2015 community.
However, g++ and clang++ (ubuntu linux 16.04 LTS) failed at linking time.
I want to compile with g++ or clang++, so I'd like to do something,
I do not get a good idea.
Is not it compatible with g++ or clang++ specifications?
Are those who are familiar with the compiler, are not you?

Answer (score 1):

GCC and Clang are correct according to the dry letter of the ISO C++ standard:

[[temp.expl.spec]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.expl.spec#13)

> An explicit specialization of a static data member of a template or an
>   explicit specialization of a static data member template is a
>   definition if the declaration includes an initializer; otherwise, it
>   is a declaration. [ Note: The definition of a static data member of a
>   template that requires default-initialization must use a
>   braced-init-list:
>
> ```
> template<> X Q<int>::x;                         // declaration
> template<> X Q<int>::x ();                      // error: declares a function
> template<> X Q<int>::x { };                     // definition
> ```
>
> — end note ]

Which when applied to your example means you just provide another declaration, not a definition. And a fix would be to add an initializer:

```
template <> int Sample <float> :: foo{}; // Default initialize `foo`
```

Or

```
template <> int Sample <float> :: foo{0.0}; // Direct initialize `foo` to 0
```

Or

```
template <> int Sample <float> :: foo = 0.0; // Copy initialize `foo` to 0
```